# Copy text from one terminal into another

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, terminal, cp

I am logged into ssh to a university account from my home computer. Then I find a file that I want to copy onto my local system. So I open a new shell terminal and am about to use `scp` to copy that file onto my system. But the path to the file on the system I am `ssh`'ed into is long so I select it with the mouse and then paste it with the mouse into the other locally connected terminal.

What I would like to do is something along the lines of: feed the output of `pwd` into a variable that is temporary and visible to all terminals even though I made it under the `ssh`'ed terminal, or some other way that I can't think of.

Comment: This is not quite an answer to your question, but a "solution" to your problem; just copy the file to an easy to type location (cp <file> /tmp, and then in the other terminal scp host:/tmp/<file> .).  No need to remember difficult paths, or commands.

Comment: Apparently, using symlink instead of copying can save you some space if the file is not small enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do that is to use an ordinary file or a named pipe.

Why not do the `scp` in the original terminal in the first place (even in the background)?

If the host system uses `proc`, in the second terminal do `cd -P /proc/PID/cwd` then do your `scp` from `.` (where PID is that of the shell which is in the cwd/pwd that you are interested in).

Comment: i have only pwdx on my distribution

Comment: for cd -P /proc/PID/cwd I get "-bash: cd: /proc/PID/pwd: No such file or directory" in the host system's terminal, should i be replacing PID with the PID of the running terminal on the system?

Comment: @Vass: Yes, the PID of the shell that you're trying to get information from, as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your terminal supports the zmodem protocol (KDE's Konsole does), and the remote system has the lrzsz package installed, you can trigger a direct transfer via the terminal using:

```
sz foo.txt
```

Konsole prompts you were to save the file and that's that. GNU screen apparently has zmodem support too.

Comment: Here's a walkthrough: http://adammonsen.com/post/256. You need `screen` as well as `rz`/`sz` on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have X forwarding active (`ssh -X`, `ForwardX11` in `~/.ssh/config`, or any other method), you can manipulate the X selection from the shell:

```
printf %s "$PWD" | xsel -i
```

Depending on your terminal emulator, you may want to set the CLIPBOARD (`xsel -bi`) instead of the PRIMARY selection (`xsel -p`). You can also use the SECONDARY selection (`xsel -si`).

You can use the middle mouse button to paste the PRIMARY selection, or (in some terminals) the CLIPBOARD with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, or you can use `xsel` (or `xsel -s` or `xsel -b`) in the shell on the other side.

There are other possible workflows, involving for example a reverse ssh connection, `~` escapes, or [zssh](http://zssh.sourceforge.net/). See [SSH easily copy file to local system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2857/885), [Download a file over an active SSH session](https://askubuntu.com/q/13382/1059). You could also mount the remote filesystem over [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

Comment: Hah, my first thought was to `xprop` stuff it in some property on the root window, but `xsel/xclip` selections make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh server running on your home machine, you may do the reverse `scp`:

`[student@university ~/rather/long/path/to/interesting/file]$ scp ./secrect.txt user@myhomesystem.net:~`