# scp to Local Machine After SSHing

Tags: ssh, scp

From my local machine I can copy files from a remote machine

```
scp remote:/some/file/path ~
```

But what if I'm already SSHed into the remote machine? Can I do something like this

```
ssh remote
cd /some/file
scp path local:~
```

where `local` somehow resolves to the machine I SSHed *from*. This would of course be possible if the local machine is running an SSH server and the remote is configured to connect to it, but that isn't always an option.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `scp`'s ugly little sister, `sftp`?

Comment: I second the `sftp` suggestion. However I would also suggest not using really complicated & annoying paths. If they are annoying to type why type them? Name them something easier to type. Finally, I would suggest using single quotes instead of double backslashes because double slashes are harder to read. Instead of `...\\\ \\\&...`, you could just do `'...\ \&...'`. See how much more readable that is?

Comment: This is one specific use case, and I appreciate your suggestions for alternatives but I'm really looking for an answer to my specific question.

Comment: I think @AndreasWiese suggestion is an answer to your question :)

Comment: Take a look at the accepted A to this AU Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13382/download-a-file-over-an-active-ssh-session. Gilles A is also a method that I've used to do what you want to0. It's the 2nd A on that same Q.

Comment: There are several approaches highlighted on this U&L Q&A as well, specifically Gilles A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4552/copy-text-from-one-terminal-into-another/4557#4557

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, I'd suggest using `sftp`:

```
$ sftp remote
user@remote's password: 
Connected to remote.
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /home/user
sftp> cd /etc
sftp> get fstab
Fetching /etc/fstab to fstab
/etc/fstab                                 100%  435     0.4KB/s   00:00    
sftp>
```

Another, rather… hacky approach would be abusing port-forwarding capabilities of SSH, combined with `nc` (a.k.a. `netcat`).  `nc` is the "swiss army knife of networking" (the smaller one… there's also `socat`, which is more the MultiTool® ;) — a kind of `cat` with networking capabilities.

The idea: tell `ssh` to forward a remote port of your remote machine to a local port on the client side and use this connection to pipe along your data using `nc`:

1. Connect to `$remote` establishing remote port forwarding:

   ```
   client:~> ssh -R 8888:localhost:8888 $remote
   ```

   This establishes a normal connection to `$remote`, but additionally tells `ssh` to listen on port `8888` on the remote side.  If something connects to port `8888` on the remote side, `ssh` will open a connection to `localhost`, port `8888` on the client side (thus, the client) and forward anything sent to remote-side's port `8888` to this port.
2. Listen on client side's port `8888` (so `ssh` has something to connect to), using `nc`.  We pipe the output (client-side) `nc` receives into `tar`, since we'll send a `tar` stream to it later:

   ```
   client:~> nc --recv-only -l -p 8888 | tar xvf -
   ```
3. On the remote side, change your current working directory anywhere you wanted.
4. If you're on the right spot, use `tar` to gather the files you want to copy and pipe them into (remote-side) `nc`, connecting to the remote-side opened port:

   ```
   server:~> cd /path/with/those/files
   server:files> tar cvf - ./some/files | nc --send-only 127.0.0.1 8888
   ```
5. Magic™ happens.

**Note:** There are at least three different implementations of `nc` out there, all with a slightly different syntax; `--send-only` and `--recv-only` are AFAIK only supported by [netcat6](http://netcat6.sourceforge.net/).  If you've an implementation that does not support those (or similar) options, you'll have to look whether `tar` exited and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> on the sender side.  `nc` usually waits forever and does not handle `EOF` (`--send-only` tells it to do and automatically close the connection).

**Another note:** You could also use `nc` directly, but by using `ssh`'s port forwarding, your data goes through the SSH connection, avoiding two problems: first, your data is still sent encrypted, and second, this also works if your client is behind a NAT'ing firewall or otherwise not directly reachable from your `$remote`.

Comment: Or set the port forward to connect to localhost:22 and then you can `scp -p 8888 file localhost:`, and not have to get out the `nc` swiss army knife :)