# Copy files from remote server to local, ignoring existing files (rsync not available)

Tags: scp

I would like to copy a directory of files from a remote server to my local machine.  As it is a large number of files, the option of ignoring existing files is desirable.
Unfortunately, `rsync` is not available for some reason (the remote server is from a CDN service, and beyond my control).

So I think I am stuck using `scp -r` on the folder in question.

Is there anyway of doing this while ignoring existing files?

Comment: Do you need to check file dates / sizes or is the file existing good enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) allows you to mount a remote directory accessed over SSH, more precisely over SFTP. Once you've mounted the remote directory, use `rsync` on what are now local files.

```
mkdir ~/cdn
sshfs cdn.example.com: ~/cdn
rsync -au ~/mystuff/dir/ ~/cdn/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could login remotely to create a list of existing files, then use that locally to create a list of files that need to be transfered and build an scp command to send them over.

Answer (score -2):

you can open the file manager like nautilus in ubuntu

and choose File->connect to Server...

insert the host address like this: sftp://hostname

insert the username and password