# Copy file over existing SSH session?

Tags: ssh, scp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH easily copy file to local system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/ssh-easily-copy-file-to-local-system)

Let's give the following example:

> I've connected to `ssh user@myserver.com`.
>   I need to copy a local file over to the remote server, without exiting SSH.

Is this possible? I know I could suspend the process via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, `scp` the file, then `fg` the SSH process back to the foreground, but is there a way to do this from within an active SSH session without leaving it?