# How to connect through sftp to a non-standard port on Midnight Commander?

Tags: sftp, mc

In Midnight Commander one can make an SFTP connection to a remote machine using:

```
cd #sh:yourusername@example.com:/home/username/
```

How can this be done when the remote machine is using a non-standard port?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whenever you want to use non-default settings for ssh, define an alias in `~/.ssh/config`. This way you can call `ssh myalias`, or have some application call `ssh myalias` under the hood, without having to worry as to how you're going to pass settings such as a non-default port, a different user name and so on.

```
Host foo
HostName example.com
Port 2222
User yourusername
```

Then in Midnight Commander: `cd #sh:foo:`

Answer (score 12):

`mc` supports "Shell links" in the respective "side menu". [This uses](https://serverfault.com/a/335689/407820) `ssh` to establish a `fish` connection (***FI**le transfer over **SH**ell filesystem*).

[image: screenshot]

[`mc` help/man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mc):

[image: help screenshot]

AFAIK there is no equivalent to `-J` ssh option, [when going through a jump server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/610135/209677).

### Other references

- [Readme about fish on mc source code](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/src/vfs/fish/helpers/README.fish)
- [fish on an old deprecated KDE project called kioslave](https://web.archive.org/web/20060214021844/http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase/kioslave/fish.html)

Comment: It seems that I already knew about this, but didn't know of the name 'shell links', but how come # hash signs are used in the other answers, including mine?  I cannot find any information on their use.

Comment: As you probably know # are usually used for comments. On [mc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mc) (_FIle transfer over SHell filesystem_ section) use the hash sign but with a slash: `/#sh:[user` (slightly different from my screenshot). This is similar to an URI but I think it isn't (officially by IANA only exist [fish](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/fish) and [ssh](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/ssh) schemes).

Comment: Do you know how reliable is FISH protocol? According to wikipedia, this seems to be designed mainly for mc: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol#:~:text=Files%20transferred%20over%20Shell%20protocol%20(FISH)%20is%20a%20network%20protocol,computers%20and%20manage%20remote%20files.). By reliability I mean can I trust the data transfer corruptions, etc.

Comment: @KFL If with _reliable_ you mean _secure_, since it runs over ssh or rsh (see the added references) it should be as ssh/rsh could be. Check if you follow ssh best practices.

Answer (score 10):

I realised that I had already tried the solution, but it did not work because I did not have `sshd` listening on the VPN interface I was using.  I have now got the internal interface listening on the standard port, so I do not even need this solution any more, but here it is:

```
cd #sh:yourusername@example.com:[port]/home/username/
```