# Is it possible to download a file locally when I've already ssh'ed into a remote computer?

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH easily copy file to local system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/ssh-easily-copy-file-to-local-system)

Most of the remote download commands seem to involve commands like scp, which are usually used without ssh'ing first (if I recall correctly).

I'd prefer a route that's as frictionless as possible.