# Upload file over ssh and execute command on the remote machine

Tags: ssh, file-copy

I am trying to find the simplest way to upload a file using ssh and after that run a command on the remote machine within the same ssh session for some post-processing, so that I don't need to login again. The upload should, if possible, show some progress indicator.

So far I looked into scp and rsync, and both are not capable of running any hooks. (I could use the `--rsync-path` parameter to execute some script *before* rsync) but I want to do post-processing. Is there any way to open a ssh session, upload, execute a command and close it again?

Comment: See also [SSH easily copy file to local system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2857)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want the `ControlMaster` mechanism in `ssh`.

Comment: Can this be done without the config file in .ssh?

Comment: You could use the equivalent `-o` options, but you really want the config file given the number of options you need to specify and the importance of their being consistent across all the invocations.

Comment: Using controlmaster I found the answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/78630/retaining-ssh-session-in-bash-script Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Well, you could just pipe the whole thing through one `ssh` command with a `cat` on the other end. Here I upload a shell script, make it executable, and run it:

```
$ cat sayhi.sh | ssh myserver 'cat > ./remotehi.sh ; chmod +x ./remotehi.sh ; ./remotehi.sh'
hello, world!
```

Comment: To get the progress you can replace `cat` with `pv`. so `pv sayhi.sh | ssh myserver 'cat > remotehi.sh...`. @ckhan the `./` isnt necessary on your cat or chmod commands. Wont hurt, but not necessary.

Comment: That is a nice solution as well. Thank you both!