# Is there a way to use inotify on remote filesystems (specifically WebDAV)?

Tags: inotify, webdav, davfs2

I have Box.com successfully mounted with `davfs2` (webdav) to a local location.
Now I am trying to trigger actions on files created and synced in the Webdav folder.

Unfortunately this is not working. I see no `inotify` events when files are synced to the local Webdav folder.
It does pick-up any local file transactions though, so I am pretty confident `inotify` is working properly.

Anyone else using Webdav (`davfs2`) and `inotify`?

Comment: Related: [How do I use inotify or named pipes over SSHFS?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144486/12779)

Comment: WebDAV is specifically mentioned in this link: [Fsnotify and FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Fsnotify-and-FUSE) (which I added to the answer below).

Answer (score 4):

According to [lwn.net - Filesystem notification, part 2: A deeper investigation of inotify](https://lwn.net/Articles/605128/) events on remote file systems (which WebDAV is) are not reported:

> For example, it means that inotify does not inform us of events on monitored objects via a remote filesystem (e.g. NFS) operation.

Notifications are implemented in the kernel. In case a file is changed, the kernel sends a notification. But on remote file systems the change doesn't involve the local kernel. Therefore no notification is generated.

For this to work, the notifications would need to be implemented on the server and then forwarded to the client.

Related:

- [inotify with NFS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231243/1013470)
- [How do I use inotify or named pipes over SSHFS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144486/12779)
- [Fsnotify and FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Fsnotify-and-FUSE) (WebDAV is specifically mentioned here.)