# inotifywait not responding to change in /proc/mounts

Tags: shell-script, mount, proc, inotify

I'm trying to get notification of the state of a problematic sshfs mount

I have tried two bash scripts

```
while inotifywait -e modify /proc/mounts; do
  echo "modified" 
done
```

and

```
inotifywait -m /proc/mounts |
while read event; do
  echo $event
done
```

To test, I'm running the following sequence, but neither of these scripts is responding.

```
 stephen@asus:~/log$ sudo umount /mnt/lexar
 stephen@asus:~/log$ sshfs michigan:/home/stephen/ /mnt/lexar
 stephen@asus:~/log$ sudo umount /mnt/lexar
 stephen@asus:~/log$ sshfs michigan:/home/stephen/ /mnt/lexar
 stephen@asus:~/log$ grep lexar /proc/mounts
 michigan:/home/stephen/ /mnt/lexar fuse.sshfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
 stephen@asus:~/log$ sudo umount /mnt/lexar
 stephen@asus:~/log$ grep lexar /proc/mounts
```

Comment: You could run `inotify` on a remote file, but [_inotify_ does not work with _sshfs_](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144486/how-do-i-use-inotify-or-named-pipes-over-sshfs) (currently). What is the problem you are trying to debug? There might be an alternative.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I don't think that the OP want to be notified of changes to files located on a sshfs, but of changes to the state of a ssh mount. inotify not working with sshfs has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @mosvy I know. One way to see if the mount is not working is to follow a file in said mount. There is even an event for that in `inotifywait`: _unmount_. It could have been a workaround to _indirectly_ know if the mount was no longer working, that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inotify` doesn't work with the proc filesystem. Though they may look as regular files, the files in the proc filesystem don't contain any static data -- the kernel makes up the data on the fly when you read them. For instance, `/proc/mounts` => `/proc/self/mounts` has the size 0, but when you read it, it *magically* happens to contain something.

But `/proc/self/mounts` and `/proc/self/mountinfo` are *pollable* -- you can `select(2)` or `poll(2)` on it for an exceptional condition. According to the [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) manpage:

> `/proc/[pid]/mounts` (since Linux 2.4.19)
>
> This file lists all the filesystems currently mounted in the process's mount namespace (see `mount_namespaces(7)`).  The format of this file is documented in `fstab(5)`.
>
> Since kernel version 2.6.15, this file is pollable: after
>   opening the file for reading, a change in this file (i.e., a
>   filesystem mount or unmount) causes `select(2)` to mark the file descriptor as having an exceptional condition, and `poll(2)` and `epoll_wait(2)` mark the file as having a priority event (`POLLPRI`).

[the same holds true for `/proc/[pid]/mountinfo`]

I don't think there's any way to do that from the shell. You can do it from `perl`, though:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $mf = "/proc/self/mountinfo";
open my $mh, "<$mf" or die "open <$mf: $!";
vec(my $ebits, $mh->fileno, 1) = 1;
while(1){
        select(undef, undef, my $e = $ebits, undef) == -1 and die "select: $!";
        print "some mount or umount happened\n";
}
```

---

A more useful example, which also shows *what* changed in `/proc/self/mountinfo`:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $mf = "/proc/self/mountinfo";
open my $mh, "<$mf" or die "open <$mf: $!";
vec(my $ebits, $mh->fileno, 1) = 1;
sub read_mounts {
        seek $mh, 0, 0 or die "seek: $!";
        my ($h, $i); $$h{$_} = ++$i while <$mh>; return $h;
}
for(my ($old, $new) = read_mounts;; $old = $new) {
        select undef, undef, my $e = $ebits, undef or die "select: $!";
        $new = read_mounts;
        for(keys %$new){
                if(exists $$old{$_}){ delete $$old{$_} }
                else{ print '+ ', $_ }
        }
        print '- ', $_ for keys %$old;
}
```