# scp to a KVM guest behind NAT

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, kvm, scp, nat

I have a KVM *guest* running on a *server* accessing it via `virt-manager`. I'm running the *guest* from *my_pc*. *server* has a public IP address and both *my_pc* and *guest* can ssh it. *guest* has a 168.192.x.x IP behind *server*'s NAT.
*server* is running Ubuntu 14.04 Server and both *my_pc* and *guest* are running Ubuntu 14.04.

Running

```
ssh -R 12345:localhost:22 me_at_server@server
```

on *guest*, and

```
ssh -L 23456:localhost:12345 me_at_server@server
```

on *my_pc*, I was able to ssh *guest* from *my_pc* simply by

```
ssh -p 23456 me_at_guest@localhost
```

as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/277218/ssh-access-to-office-host-behind-nat-router).

However, I am not able to `scp` anything from *my_pc* to *guest*.
I have tried the master connection approach described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/ssh-easily-copy-file-to-local-system) by adding the config both on *my_pc* and *guest*, but no success.

How can I copy files from *my_pc* to the KVM *guest* and back?

Comment: Port selection is with capital `-P` for `scp`.

Comment: thanks @RalphRönnquist ! that worked. 
I was doing `scp -p 23456 my_local_file_on_my_pc.zip me_at_guest@localhost`, whereas putting a capital `-P` did the magic.


Is this an ok way to scp?