# How to copy a local file when I connect using ssh

Tags: ssh

I connect to my remote server using SSH, and I don't enter a password during login as I have setup a SSH key already.

How can I copy a file from my local laptop to my server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy. If you can SSH, you should be able to use `scp` or `rsync`:

`scp /path/to/source <uname>@<server>:/path/to/dest`

if you have to use a non-standard port, use the `-P` option. See `man scp`.

Rsync is quite nice if you're looking for syncing multiple files with extensive options. I'll let you research that on your own though ;)

You can also see [this very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/ssh-easily-copy-file-to-local-system?rq=1) for more information.