# Transferring files between a server and a PC through another server (who was size limitations)

Tags: files, size, file-transfer

I am working in a server, to which I need to enter from another server. Example:

```
ssh user@login1.de                       
ssh user@login2.de
```

Note that I can't connect to `login2` directly, but only from `login1`.

Whenever I want to transfer files from `login2` to my computer, I first have to transfer it from `login2` to `login1`, and then from `login1` to my computer. The problem is that `login1` cannot contain files larger than 1 GB (when `login2` can), so its sort of a bottleneck.

My question is, is there a way to still use `login1` as some sort of medium between my computer and `login2`, and still transfer files larger than 1 GB?

Thanks.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831329/how-to-transfer-a-file-between-two-remote-servers-using-scp-from-a-third-local

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download a file from a host I can only SSH to through another host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537319/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-a-host-i-can-only-ssh-to-through-another-host)

Answer (score 2):

The key buzzword you're missing is "jump host", because that's what your login1 seems to be: a small-sized gateway that's not supposed to do anything that regulate where you can continue on to.

Given a recent enough `ssh`, you should be able to do

```
scp -o proxyjump=user@login1.de user@login2.de:/pth/to/file /pth/to/dest
```

and on older ssh clients, it would be

```
scp -o proxycommand=“ssh user@login1.de -W %h:%p” user@login2.de:/pth/to/src /pth/to/tg
```

In both cases, the connection will be opened to `login1` and tunneled through to `login2`. (This probably requires that you either use agent forwarding or password authentication on `login2`, i.e. there is no private key on `login1`.)

In either case, and once you've verified that it works, you can stick the option in your `~/.ssh/config` like so:

```
host login2.de
   ProxyJump user@login1.de
#   ProxyCommand ssh user@login1.de -W %h:%p
```

and then your ssh connections to `login2` will always use the jump host without any need for explicit `-o proxy...` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Login to `login1.de` server via `ssh` from with your local server and do as following.

```
scp -3 user@login2.de:/file user@mylocal:/path/to/transfer
```

This will route `scp` traffic from server2 into your local server through server1.

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution, however I don't have a local server, its my private machine (if that even makes sense).

Comment: your need a [meter connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2869/72456) then

Comment: Is there any other way? opening a local server seems to be beyond my capabilities.