# How can I transfer files from my local system to another via a gateway system (and vice versa) via SSH/SFTP?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sftp

I have the following situation,

`(1) local machine` ↔︎ `(2) cluster gateway` ↔︎ `(3) cluster machine`

and I want to transfer files from my (1) to the (3) and vice versa. There is no way to directly ssh from (1) into (3) though, I can only reach (3) from within (2). Currently I first transfer files from (1) to (2) via sftp, and then from (2) to (3). This is quite cumbersome, in particular since I have a very limited storage on (2).

I found that the answer is likely an ssh tunnel. But I am not sure if this is indeed the way to do it, nor do I know how to set one up or to use it.

I am not an IT guy, and these things are sometimes hard for me to see through. In particular with ssh and ssh keys I want to be careful and make sure that I know what I am doing.

Does anyone perhaps have some insights?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a recent OpenSSH (8.0) *locally*, you can use the [`-J` (jump) switch](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#J):

```
scp -J user@intermediate /local/path/file.txt user@target:/remote/path/
```

---

With older versions (but at least 7.3), you can use [`ProxyJump` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump):

```
scp -o ProxyJump=user@intermediate /local/path/file.txt user@target:/remote/path
```

---

There are other options like `ProxyCommand` or port forwarding, which you can use on even older versions of OpenSSH. These are covered in [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663)

---

For download, see [How can I download a file from a host I can only SSH to through another host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537319/119732#537328)